# Calculate date range and return true

Tags: java

I want to compare 2 dates with Java 8+ and return false if the password is old than 45 days. All should be into one line if possible because I want to use it for Spring Security. Is this possible?

Something like this:

```
boolean isExpired = password_changed_at.minusDays(45).isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());
```

EDIT:

```
private boolean compareExpireDates(LocalDateTime password_changed_at) {

        long days_left = Duration.between(password_changed_at, LocalDateTime.now()).toDays();

        if (days_left > 45) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: everything is possible if you can post the code

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post is updated.

Comment: The above line is not working? any issue? or error? @PeterPenzov

Comment: Since lines do not have a length limit in Java you can write every program in one line.

Comment: is this correct? `boolean isExpired = password_changed_at.minusDays(45).isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());`

Comment: This will be always true unless you allow password changes in the future.

Comment: Can you show me what is the correct code please?

Comment: Before you go any further, consider [this](https://www.sans.org/security-awareness-training/blog/time-password-expiration-die), [this](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/problems-forcing-regular-password-expiry) and [this](https://techcrunch.com/2019/06/02/password-expiration-is-dead-long-live-your-passwords/).

Comment: I added another attempt. Can you tell me how I can reduce the code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are in right approach, no need of any `if` block just in one statement return `true` if duration days greater than 45 or else `false`. You can also refactor this method to accept the number of days

```
private boolean compareExpireDates(LocalDateTime password_changed_at,long noOfDays) {

   return Duration.between(password_changed_at, LocalDateTime.now()).toDays()>noOfDays
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but it may be worth pointing out that password expiration policies are nowadays discouraged by several security-related organizations. Also, methods called "compareXXX" typically return an int (as in Comparator); a method returning a boolean might better be called "hasExpired".